# Importing in Mass from LaTeX to LyX

Tags: lyx, import

I have tons of tables stored in LaTeX format that I would like to import into LyX.
Doing this manually (through file-->import-->latex(plain) ) will take forever and a day.
Using tex2latex (text2lyx -f -d basic_R.tex) reports the following error:

```
" ...EL/Masters Tburg/Output/Bolivia/Regs/regs_
                                                  trends_basic_R.tex
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed."
```

Despite the same file importing neatly using the file-->import option.

Any ideas what's going wrong or an alternative way of importing LaTeX into LyX in mass?

Comment: The basic problem here seems to be underscores in filenames...

Comment: can you post a minimal example? I cannot reproduce. In general, having spaces in file names or directories is not recommended (e.g. it's a good idea to change "Masters Tburg" to "MastersTburg".

Comment: Following up on the comments above: if you haven't already, can you try removing all underscores and spaces from file and folder names, and try again.